# Datatables change color background

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, server-side

I'm developing a table based on Datatables with server side process.

I want to change the background color for each cell if the value is different from the previous row in the same cell position

This is my output table generated with server side process:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Acer computer</td>
        <td>Ram 32 gb</td>
        <td>$500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Acer computer</td>
        <td>Ram 32 gb</td>
        <td>$500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Acer computer</td>
        <td>Ram 16 gb</td>
        <td>$320</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the background color of the TD for the second TR because the value changed.

I tryed with createdCell but with bad results.

> https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell

Is possible with datatables? Is there a jsfiddle available for help?

Comment: Lets see how you initialise the dataTable, i.e what you have tried with `createdCell`...? It is not so clear what "*change the background color for each cell if the value is different from the previous row in the same cell position*" mean. This will change each time you have a different value, i.e you will need a lot of colors, and which color to use?

Comment: @davidkonrad i followed the example for the datatables server side process https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html .
i posted the output of the table, but what i'm tring to do is to mark the value when the table is initialized in `$(document).ready(function().` I'll have only one item per page, se i will use only one color to mark the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with Datatables API here the code:

```
"columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        if (row > 0) {
            old = table.data(row - 1);
            if ( cellData != old.row(row).column(col).data()[row-1] ) {
                previous_row = old.row(row).column(col).nodes()[row-1]
                $(previous_row).css('background-color', '#FFFF99')
            }
        }
    }
    } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have a way to check if the state of the value has changed. What I suggest is to set data attribute in the cell as the example below and then use css to change the color.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Acer computer</td>
    <td>Ram 32 gb</td>
    <td>$500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-changed='true'>Acer computer</td>
    <td>Ram 32 gb</td>
    <td>$500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Acer computer</td>
    <td>Ram 16 gb</td>
    <td>$320</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: uhm no, because i need to change the backgoud for each cell with a different value, for example, i like to mark in the second TR the ram value and the price. The number of rows are dynamic for each product

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Edit this code with your database values
**by using your html code, i have done a simple solution with jQuery**
**using .each() function**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var n=1;
    var j=0;
    var prev_val = function(eq_no){
    return  $('table tr:eq('+eq_no+') td:last').text();
   }
  $('table tr').each(function(){
         var index_val = $('table tr').index($(this));
     var fill_val = $(this).find('td:last').text();
     if(index_val == n){
        if(fill_val == prev_val(j)){

        }
        else{
        $(this).find('td:last').css({"background":"#0d0d0d"});
        }
        n++;
            j++;  

      }
    });
});
```

try this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/s05u3th0/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will test it in the next days, Is possible to have the same script for datatables? Thanks

Comment: You can add your database variables in the above code,

Comment: Will not work because the jQuery will loaded before that the table will populated, i post the asnware with datatables code. Thx for yur script